# Racket: Sharing a script/libraries with another user on the same system

Tags: linux, racket

I have a script I wrote in Racket a few years ago that I'd like to share with a colleague who is using my same Linux workstation, but with a different home folder. I am able to run it just fine from my account but when I have them call the script from their account, they get an error:

```
/home/me/racket/script:10:9: collection not found
  for module path: mylibrary
  collection: "mylibrary"
  in collection directories:
   /home/colleague/.racket/6.4/collects
   /share/apps/racket/racket-6.4/share/racket/collects
   ... [155 additional linked and package directories]
  context...:
   show-collection-err
   standard-module-name-resolver
```

Since it seemed to only be looking for my library in the colleagues directory, I thought I might be able to fix it by adding the following code to the script in order to make them use my collection path before requiring the modules.

```
(current-library-collection-paths
 (list "/home/me/.racket/6.4/collects"
       "/share/apps/racket/racket-6.4/share/racket/collects"))
```

I got the idea from reading: https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/collects.html. From that source, it looks like I could also set the `PLTCOLLECTS` environment variable to have the same effect.

While I was still able to run the script, it still didn't work for my colleague. This procedure obviously didn't do what I thought it did.

How can I do what I had intended-how can I let them run the script reusing my Racket environment?

I did install them globally:

> raco pkg install  --scope installation -- mypackage.zip

Comment: It sounds like you should put your library in a [package](http://docs.racket-lang.org/pkg/index.html) and distribute it that way rather than via some other ad-hoc method of distribution.

Comment: I suppose installing the package into the global collection folder would be reasonable. I will have to involve my system administrator for this. Is this just as easy as `raco pkg install` as root? Or is there some option I'm missing?